# Simple Custom jQuery Rotator Not Working in IE 7, 8, or 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, show-hide

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/markrummel/vPcrX/

This code works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE 10, but not in IE 7, 8, or 9.

I have tested it via IE 10's Developer Tool and it doesn't work when I first open it in IE 7, 8, or 9. However, after I open the Developer Tool it starts working in IE 7, 8, and 9. I have also tested in the older IE browsers via [Microsoft's Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3702) and the rotator isn't working.

You can see the whole page here: http://melaniejaderummel.com. However, I think the issue is isolated to the jQuery code since it doesn't work in the stripped-down [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markrummel/vPcrX/).

**Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated!**

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="testimonials">
    <p data-testimonial="1">“Testimonial Content” – Julie S.</p>
    <p data-testimonial="2">“Testimonial Content” – Melissa D.</p>
    <!--repeated; 10 total testimonials-->
</div>
```

**The relevant CSS:**

```
#testimonials p {display:none;}
```

**And finally, here is my javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var shownTestimonials = [];

    displayTestimonials(shownTestimonials);

    function displayTestimonials(shownTestimonials) {
        var totalTestimonials = 10;

        console.log(shownTestimonials);
        //console.log(shownTestimonials.length);

        if (shownTestimonials.length == 0 || shownTestimonials.length == totalTestimonials) {
            var shownTestimonials = [];
        }

        function getNewTestimonial(totalTestimonials) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * totalTestimonials) + 1; //random number between 1 and 10
        }

        var currentTestimonial = $('#testimonials p.visible').attr('data-testimonial');
        var newTestimonial = getNewTestimonial(totalTestimonials);

        console.log(currentTestimonial);

        if (currentTestimonial == null) {
            $('#testimonials p[data-testimonial="' + newTestimonial + '"]').addClass('visible').fadeIn(700);
            shownTestimonials.push(newTestimonial);
        } else {

            var newExists = 1;

            while (newExists > -1) {
                var newTestimonial = getNewTestimonial(totalTestimonials);
                var newExists = $.inArray(newTestimonial, shownTestimonials)
                console.log(newExists);
            }

            $('#testimonials p[data-testimonial="' + currentTestimonial + '"]').removeClass('visible').fadeOut(600);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#testimonials p[data-testimonial="' + newTestimonial + '"]').addClass('visible').fadeIn(700);
                shownTestimonials.push(newTestimonial);
            }, 700);
        } //end else

        setTimeout(function () {
            displayTestimonials(shownTestimonials);
        }, 12000);
    } //end displayTestimonials();

}); //end $(document).ready
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove or comment out the `console.log` statements. IE chokes on them unless the console is open (in the versions of IE that have the dev tools).

Per [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2011/05/26/console-log-say-goodbye-to-javascript-alerts-for-debugging.aspx):

> Keep in mind you will not be able to see the output unless you have
>   the developer tools open. You can see the console output on either the
>   Console or Script tabs. Be careful when using console for debugging.
>   If you leave a call to the console object in your code when you move
>   to production and you do not have the developer tools displayed you
>   will get an error message telling you console is undefined. To avoid the error message, you either need to remove all the console method calls from your code, or you need to add a check to make sure console exists before calling any methods.

Comment: It works! I commented out the `console.log` lines of code. I would not have figured this out on my own in a million years. Thank you! Also, thanks for the MSDN reference. I will be sure to get rid of my `console.log` lines when moving to production. Thanks again!